# Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6 - SSL Configuration not working

Tags: java, ssl, websphere-liberty

I"m attempting to setup an SSL configuration. The relevent lines in my server.xml are:

```
<sslDefault sslRef="defaultSSLSettings" />
<ssl id="defaultSSLSettings" 
     keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
     trustStoreRef="trustedtKeyStore" 
     sslProtocol="TLS"  />
```

However, when my server starts up, I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKE0701E: [com.ibm.ws.clientcontainer.remote.server.ClientSupportImpl(395)] The activate method has thrown an exception Bundle:com.ibm.ws.clientcontainer.remote.server(id=164) java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transport addressses configured for sslAlias: defaultSSLSettings with supports: 38 and requires: 6
    at com.ibm.ws.clientcontainer.remote.server.ClientSupportImpl.createMyPoa(ClientSupportImpl.java:328)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transport addressses configured for sslAlias: defaultSSLSettings with supports: 38 and requires: 6
    at com.ibm.ws.security.csiv2.server.config.tss.ServerConfigHelper.extractSSLTransport(ServerConfigHelper.java:219)
    ... 1 more

[ERROR   ] CWWKE0701E: [com.ibm.ws.clientcontainer.remote.server.ClientSupportImpl(395)] Failed creating the component instance; see log for reason Bundle:com.ibm.ws.clientcontainer.remote.server(id=164)   
[WARNING ] WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.v11.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension.internalProcessAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[WARNING ] WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.v11.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://mq93943q.maple.fg.rbc.com:9080/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application SecurityPOC-ear started in 3.574 seconds.
[ERROR   ] CWWKE0701E: [com.ibm.ws.management.j2ee.mejb.service.ManagementEJBService(68)] The setServerStarted method has thrown an exception Bundle:com.ibm.ws.management.j2ee.mejb(id=264) java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.osgi.internal.EJBRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transport addressses configured for sslAlias: defaultSSLSettings with supports: 38 and requires: 6
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.osgi.internal.EJBContainerImpl.startSystemModule(EJBContainerImpl.java:225)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.osgi.internal.EJBRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transport addressses configured for sslAlias: defaultSSLSettings with supports: 38 and requires: 6
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.osgi.internal.EJBRuntimeImpl.startSystemModule(EJBRuntimeImpl.java:944)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transport addressses configured for sslAlias: defaultSSLSettings with supports: 38 and requires: 6
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:587)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transport addressses configured for sslAlias: defaultSSLSettings with supports: 38 and requires: 6
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote.internal.EJBRemoteRuntimeImpl.createPOA(EJBRemoteRuntimeImpl.java:294)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transport addressses configured for sslAlias: defaultSSLSettings with supports: 38 and requires: 6
    at com.ibm.ws.security.csiv2.server.config.tss.ServerConfigHelper.extractSSLTransport(ServerConfigHelper.java:219)
    ... 1 more
```

Googling has failed me. I can't seem to uncover the root cause. Does anybody know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your whole server.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

At this point I think you've found a bug.  It will take me some time to verify the details.  Meanwhile I think you could try either:

change your snippet to just modify the default ssl entry:

```
<!-- sslDefault sslRef="defaultSSLConfig" no longer needed, this is the default--/>
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" 
     keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
     trustStoreRef="trustedtKeyStore" 
     sslProtocol="TLS"  />
```

or add this to your server.xml:

```
<iiopEndpoint id="defaultIiopEndpoint" iiopPort="2809">
    <iiopsOptions  iiopsPort="9402" sslRef="defaultSSLSettings"/>
</iiopEndpoint>
```

Either one of these should work.

-- I haven't been able to reproduce this problem yet.  Could you see how simple you can make your server.xml and still have the problem, and post it?  many thanks.

Comment: Taking out the <sslDefault sslRef="defaultSSLSettings" /> solved the problem.
I'll work on getting you a minimal server.xml. I'm using Liberty 8.5.5.6, running Oracle JKD 8, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Also, your SSL config shows - trustStoreRef="trusted*t*KeyStore" . Is that a typo (additional *t*) or did you actually define a trustStore with that exact name?